# Loading GIF becomes choppy near end

Tags: jquery, css

It's a small problem, but one that bugs me none the less. I've got a loading GIF set as a background-image. When the page has loaded all of it's content, the background-image changes to an arrow. Very simple build.

Problem is, on the first visit, before anything is cached, the GIF becomes really choppy a couple seconds before the page has finished loading it's content. Anyone know a fix or workaround?

I've looked around online but couldn't find anything to do specifically with GIFs becoming choppy in a situation like this. Thanks in advance!

[Test-site](http://rocko-design.com/testing3) (temporarily online)

HTML

```
<a href=".start" id="next"></a>
```

CSS

```
.cbp-af-header a#next {
    display:block;
    background-image:url('../images/loading.gif');
    background-size:30px 30px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:550px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor:default;
}

.cbp-af-header a#next:hover {
    background-color:#000;
}

.cbp-af-header a.next-ready {
    background-image:url('../images/raquo-down.png') !important;
    background-size:19px 13px !important;
    cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
            $('a#next').addClass('next-ready');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The GIF becomes choppy when the processor is busy (for example, looking at your site when the fonts are being loaded makes the GIF choppy on my end) - as such I'd not think there's much you can do, apart maybe for making the animation even less resource hungry. Have you tried creating a CSS3 animation on a single-framed GIF?

Comment: That's the nature of the web... things display while things are loading.  Why wouldn't you want that?  The only thing you could do is pre-load with JS and then set the background image.

Comment: Loads fine for me.  i7 / 16gb / SSD / 2gbVid tho.

Comment: Thanks @eithed. Using CSS3 has fixed it for Chrome (PC & Mac), but has had no effect on FF (PC & Mac) and doesn't work in IE9 or below. If I can't find another solution, this will do fine. [New Temp Link](http://www.rocko-design.com/testing4)